# MissingDummyValueError: Either<Failure, Class> This means Mockito was not smart enough to generate a dummy value of type 'Either<Failure, Class>'

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, mockito

I'm trying to write a test with the Either package, but I'm getting the following error. What is the provideDummy mentioned in the error?
​

```
MissingDummyValueError: Either<Failure, Weather>
This means Mockito was not smart enough to generate a dummy value of type
'Either<Failure, Weather>'. Please consider using either 'provideDummy' or 
'provideDummyBuilder'
functions to give Mockito a proper dummy value.

Please note that due to implementation details Mockito sometimes needs users
to provide dummy values for some types, even if they plan to explicitly stub
all the called methods.

package:mockito/src/dummies.dart 156:3                             dummyValue
test/helpers/test_helper.mocks.dart 72:17                          
MockWeatherRepository.getCurrentWeather
test/domain/use_cases/get_current_weather_usecase_test.dart 31:29  main.<fn>
```

How can i solve it ?

Comment: The message tells you what you do: call `provideDummy` with a dummy value for `Either<Failure, Weather>`. For example: `provideDummy(Either<Failure, Weather>())`.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/697.